# Magento Enterprise Lite

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-inc

For trainings, Magento provides an VirtualBox Ubuntu VM with a version of Magento described as "Magento Enterprise Lite".

- What are the key differences between EE and EE Lite?
- Is this version of Magento publicly available?
- Is there anything preventing developers from using this for EE development?

**Edit**

I know how to obtain it. Any thoughts on what the license agreement is with this version and what the limitations are?

Comment: I used it to develope Ikonoshirt_PBKDF2 :-)

Comment: Re license, I'm sure that is specified in the TOS for the training material. Likely NDA'd and academic use only; my guess anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is licensed for training use only. Any commercial use is a violation of those terms.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Any thoughts on what features it lacks from regular EE?

Comment: FPC for sure, possibly checkout depending on the version.

Answer (score 3):

- yes, you need to register for one of the free trainings....
- not really, as there is no mechanism that checks for the license

more details:

- register for http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/on-demand (it's a checkout process)
- you will receive access to some Magento U portal stuff (login into your MagentoCommerce acount, then click on Magento U)
- in there after you tick a checkbox about terms and conditions you get access to EE Lite (not sure which version is in there now).